# Subject in Participle Phrase

Tags: grammar

> It's been a drag taking you* on walks.
>   (*dog)

I've been told like you should omit the subject in participle phrase when the two subjects in main clause and dependent clause are the same and must not when different.

Shouldn't the sentence be rephrased like this?:

> It's been a drag me taking you on walks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject is the same in both clauses, and it is “I” - this subject is never explicitly used but is understood. The sentence means something like

> **I feel like** it’s been a drag **when I have** taken you on walks.

*You* is the object- the person (or animal) the subject is talking to. In this sentence *you* is not the subject.